# Restoring the pictures of user profiles in SharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, restore

After a full synchronization and incorrectly installed connection filters a lot of users have been removed from User Profile Store. After that, users have been restored using the import option.

#### Question: How to restore the pictures of user profiles as well as the other personal data?

Comment: Are the pictures coming from AD? Other data is edited by users or imported by ad? Are you importing or exporting from ad?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know where these photo came from originally. At this moment I cannot clarify this from anybody, but this issue has to be solved urgently. 
The other data is present in AD DS, but when I set import direction in user properties and run full sync nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

If the photos are still present in the My Site Host User Photo library you may have luck with Update-SPProfilePhotoStore. The rest of their data is stored in the Profile Database and unless you have a backup is lost.

Comment: Great! Thanks. My Site Host User Photo library is completely empty. Is it possible that these photos are stored in the Exchange? Because by clicking on the photo in my site it opens a new window with exchange online mail client.

Comment: If the user uploads the photo, they go to the My Site Host. However you may have it configured differently as part of the user profile import.

Comment: To return to the issue I have success with the cmdlet above and all the photos are now in Profile Pictures folder. I also have already activated synchronization with Exchange High-Res Photo option ([link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jenstr/2012/08/17/using-exchange-2013-high-resolution-photos-from-sharepoint-server-2013/)) and now I need to run forced update the profile pictures. Maybe you know to perform this?

Comment: According to your link there is no "job" it only happens when the user takes some action in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

In the sitution you are, i think best option is restore the UPA. So now it is depend if you have the backups SharePoint. You should have either farm backup(including services) or UPA content Database.

[Here is the technet which will explain the steps](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985419.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible that these photos are stored in the Exchange?

Comment: Possible, yes but normally they are stored in the AD.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any backup. Anyway the link is very useful. Will save to bookmarks.

Comment: What will happen to a list items, where users are the owners if I restore the UPA?